# Objective C autorelease object with block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have an object that I use like this

```
[PeripheralManager readValueForCharacteristic:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_TX_POWER_LEVEL]
                                                        inService:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE_TX_POWER]
                                                  completionBlock:^(NSData *value) {
                                                          //code
                                                  }];
```

The problem is that if I doesn't save the object in a strong property when I call `completionBlock` the app crashes.

You can say "Save your PeripheralManager in a strong property"... well there are some situation in witch I have to read a value and than another value again e so on, maybe for 3 or 4 times.

In other situation is possible call class method that returns some values in a block and the block is not deallocated. Is there a way to keep mi PeripheralManager in memory ?

---

**Edit**

```
    + (id)readValueForCharacteristic:(CBUUID *)cUUID
                           inService:(CBUUID *)sUUID
                     completionBlock:(completionBlock)completionBlock
    {
        return [[self alloc] initForReadValueForCharacteristic:cUUID
                                                     inService:sUUID
                                               completionBlock:completionBlock];
    }

    - (id)initForWriteValue:(unsigned char)value
     forCharacteristic:(CBUUID *)cUUID
             inService:(CBUUID *)sUUID
       completionBlock:(completionBlock)completionBlock
    {
        self = [super init];

        if (self)
        {
            self.completionBlock = [completionBlock copy];
            self.accessType = PeripheralAccessTypeWrite;
            self.valueToSet = value;

            if (cUUID && sUUID)
            {
                self.sUUID = sUUID;
                self.cUUID = cUUID;

                self.connectedPeripheral = [[BLEManager manager] getConnectedPeripheral];
                self.connectedPeripheral.delegate = self;

                if (self.connectedPeripheral && self.connectedPeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected)
                {
                    [self.connectedPeripheral discoverServices:@[sUUID]];
                }
            }
            else NSLog(@"cUUID and sUUID are mandatory");
        }

        return self;
    }
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
//    NSLog(@"didDiscoverServices");

    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services)
    {
        if ([service.UUID isEqual:self.sUUID])
        {
            [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[self.cUUID] forService:service];
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (service.UUID.UUIDString.length >= 8)
    {
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
        {
            if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:self.cUUID])
            {
                if (self.accessType == PeripheralAccessTypeRead)
                {
                    self.connectedCharacteristic = characteristic;
                    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
                    [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
                }
                else
                {
                    self.connectedCharacteristic = characteristic;
                    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];

                    unsigned char dat = self.valueToSet;
                    NSLog(@"dat %i", dat);
                    NSData * valueData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&dat length:1];

                    NSLog(@"valueData %@",valueData);

                    [peripheral writeValue:valueData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        NSString * characteristicName = [self getCharacteristicName:characteristic];
        NSData * value = [self readValueFromCharacteristic:characteristic];

        NSLog(@"update %@: %@",characteristicName ,value);

       self.completionBlock(value);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What `PeripheralManager` object? It looks like `PeripheralManager` is a class and you're calling a class method. Also, if your block references an object and **if the block is copied**, then the block will hold a strong reference to that object. So, your explanation of why you think the crash is happening doesn't seem likely. Are you using ARC? (Under ARC, blocks are always copied to the heap.) If not, are you copying the completion block if you keep it past its definition context? In any case, show your code and show the crash details.

Comment: +-[readValue...]'s implementation should -[copy] block under MRC or store it in a copy property / strong ivar under ARC. Lifetime of peripheralManager itself is up to it's owner (not shown here). As Ken noted, diagnosis is likely wrong.

Comment: I edit the question with implementation code @KenThomases